# Should we migrate "How to pronounce X" questions to EL&U?

Tags: discussion, migration, off-topic

Are pronunciation questions on-topic on SO? They certainly are on English Language and Usage, which is starting to get questions that have been previously asked on SO.

- 6 hours ago on EL&U: [How to pronounce LINQ?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11302/how-to-pronounce-linq)
- 9½ months ago on SO: [How to pronounce LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659330/how-to-pronounce-linq)
- 6 hours ago on EL&U: [How to pronounce GUID](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11297/how-to-pronounce-guid)
- 8 months ago on SO: [How is GUID pronounced? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940403/how-is-guid-pronounced)

Just searching SO for "how to pronounce" returns [31 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22how+to+pronounce%22), many of them closed as off-topic or subjective and argumentative. I think at least some of them could find an all-new shiny home over at EL&U.

(Searching for "pronounce" alone returns a whopping [227 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pronounce), and searching for "pronunciation" returns around [177](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pronunciation), but many of them are not relevant here.)

There's even a tag [pronunciation](/questions/tagged/pronunciation) on SO, currently comprising 26 questions. Do they really belong on SO? If yes, how do we go about handling possible cross-site dupes on EL&U? We can't say they're off-topic *there*.

Comment: To me, pronunciation of LINQ and GUID are more programming questions than 'English' questions. Who but a programmer would 'know' the answer anyway?

Comment: @Benjol: it's not like we don't have programmers on EL&U. In fact, out of the top 20 users by rep, 17 come from StackOverflow (some of them 10k users, many 3k, quite a few registered for 24+ months). And I'm just being too lazy to check every user in the top 100, you'll see many familiar faces there as well.

Comment: Personally, I don't care how people (mis)pronounce programming terms. I hear gif and jif, gwid and gyooid, S.Q.L. and Sequel, etc. And I simply avoid saying PostGreSQL at all costs.

Comment: I think EL&U is dominated by US English, whereas there is a far wider user base on SO, which, I think, makes it a better place for questions about the pronunciation of programming terms when it is likely that it will vary a great deal between different flavours of English.

Comment: @Remou: that is simply not true. And frankly, I think you do EL&U a great disservice by claiming that. Most regulars aren't even from the US. Out of the aforementioned 20 top users, only 8 come from the States. We cover *all* varieties of English, including Indian, Australian, New Zealand, you name it.

Comment: @Remou: I agree with @RegDwight. BTW, if you check you'll notice he is the highest-rated poster on the site, and English is not even his native tongue. Many of the top posters are not even native English speakers, still less American.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's little point in going looking for questions to migrate - especially if the questions you find are more than a couple of months old.

You'll probably end up with duplicates - as you've demonstrated with your two examples.

Far better just to close the **old** ones as off topic (or flag for a moderator to do that). Just vote to migrate the **new** ones (after checking it won't be a duplicate).

Answer (score 3):

I'd say pronunciation of jargon-y acronyms is a field specific thing and doesn't belong on EL&U.

For programming acronyms, I'd say this is a question about how *programmers* deal with them and new ones belong on programmers.SE not stackoverflow.com. I can't bring myself to care about old ones.

Comment: I think questions of topicality for EL&U belongs on EL&U meta, but for what it's worth I'm inclined to agree with you.