# Is there a stack exchange site where I can ask how to pronounce an acronym?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we migrate “How to pronounce X” questions to EL&U?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77910/should-we-migrate-how-to-pronounce-x-questions-to-elu)

I was talking with someone about how SAP (the software) should be pronounced.  Should it be spelled out S A P or should you say "sap", as in the tree?

Is there a good stack exchange site for that kind of question?

Comment: That depends, is it an initialism or an acronym?

Comment: In all of their marketing material they sound out each letter: S-A-P. No wonder, since "sap" is pretty insulting.

Comment: I'm pretty clear on it being S A P.  But I'm not clear if there's a site for asking about other acronyms, and pronouncing an acronym other than the common way is the surest method to show you don't know what's going on.

Comment: I would say on [English Language SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

But in general most acronyms are pronounced differently by different people.

Answer (score 1):

I would say on [English Language SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/)

But in general most acronyms are pronounced differently by different people.